# My created function won't accept an array as one of the arguments

Tags: python

I've written a function that takes two arguments, one for no. dimensions and another for no. simulations. The function does exactly what is needed (calculating the volume of a unit hypersphere), however when I wish to plot the function over a range of dimensions it returns an error: ''list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'.

My function is the following,

```
def hvolume(ndim, nsim):
    ob = [np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,(nsim, ndim))]
    ob = np.concatenate(ob) 
    i = 0
    res = []
    while i <= nsim-1:
        arr = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(ob[i])))
        i += 1
        res.append(arr)
    N = nsim
    n = ndim
    M = len([i for i in res if i <= 1])
    return ((2**n)*M/N)
```

The error traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-192-4c4a2c778637>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('H:/Documents/Python Scripts/Q4ATTEMPT.py', wdir='H:/Documents/Python Scripts')

File "C:\Users\u1708511\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\u1708511\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "H:/Documents/Python Scripts/Q4ATTEMPT.py", line 20, in <module>
print(hvolume(d, 2))

File "H:/Documents/Python Scripts/Q4ATTEMPT.py", line 4, in hvolume
ob = [np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,(nsim, ndim))]

File "mtrand.pyx", line 1307, in mtrand.RandomState.uniform

File "mtrand.pyx", line 242, in mtrand.cont2_array_sc

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I really have no idea where to go from here, and have searched thoroughly online for how to resolve this. Unfortunately I'm a beginner with this!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is on line 4.

Comment: please post the full error traceback.

Comment: what is module `np`?

Comment: @SRTHellKitty posted.

Comment: @user803422 numpy imported as np.

Comment: please see my answer, you need to re-think the logic of this code slightly to handle lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply try your first line in the function;

```
ob = [np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,(nsim, ndim))]
```

with a list as one of the variables like so;

```
[np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,([1,2], 2))]
```

you will get the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is because the uniform command it looking for an integer, not a list. You will need to make a for loop if you would like to handle lists.

Comment: I understand. Will have another go at rewriting it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One pattern I use for situations like this would be to begin the function with a block to handle the case of if they're iterators. Something like this for example.

```
from collections import Iterator

def hvolume(ndim, nsim):
    outputs = []
    if isinstance(ndim, Iterator):
        for ndim_arg in ndim:
            outputs.append(hvolume(ndim_arg, nsim))
    if isinstance(nsim, Iterator):
        for nsim_arg in nsim:
            outputs.append(hvolume(ndim, nsim_arg))
    if len(outputs) == 0:  # neither above is an Iterator
        # ... the rest of the function but it appends to outputs
    return outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the input parameters of your method "hvolume", it seems that you give a list either nsim or ndim, which should be both integer values. That makes the uniform throw a TypeError Exception.